# C++ array inserting to a double vector

Tags: c++, vector

If I declare

```
vector< vector <double > > V;
```

how can I insert `(3.0, 4.0)` as the first element?

Comment: I think a vector of type `std::pair<double, double>` would be more appropiate.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Is it faster than vector of vectors? Also, how do I insert a pair into the vector?

Comment: `v.push_back(make_pair(3.0, 4.0))`

Comment: How do I refer to it in the array? Normally I do array[i][j] but now this seems to not work

Comment: `v[i].first` or `v[i].second`

Comment: You just do `V[i]`, you can get the first element of the pair like this: `V[i].first` the second: `V[i].second`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/) to insert a pair of doubles into your vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> V; 
V.push_back(std::make_pair(3.0, 4.0));
```

Comment: I realise OP probably didn't know what they were asking, but this doesn't answer the question as it stands. Maybe you could explain why this is a solution?

Comment: @juanchopanza The OP wanted to insert vectors of length two into another vector. There is no reason for another vector when you can use pair (which is already of size two).

Comment: Maybe OP needed access via `[][]`, in which case vector of `std::array` would have been more suitable.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe but they didn't clarify. Pair makes more sense if the two numbers are related in some way; an (x,y) point for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You cant add 2 values to that 2d vector, that 2d vector only store one value of type double in M x N positions.

what you can do is create a struct for example:

```
struct SPoint
{
  double X;
  double Y;
};
```

and then add the points like this:

```
vector< vector <SPoint > > v; 
SPoint point = {3.0, 3.4};

v.push_back ( std::vector<SPoint >()
v[0].push_back(point);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you want to insert an element into a pre-existing vector, or into a new, empty one. In either case, you can use the `std::vector` `std::initializer_list` constructor to initialize or assign as appropriate:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> v1;
  v1.push_back({3.0,4.0}); // push first element using initializer_list

  std::vector<std::vector<double>> v2(10);
  v2[0] = {3.0, 4.0}; // assign value to pre-existing vector

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++03:

```
vector<vector<double>> V;
V.push_back(std::vector<double>(2));
V[0][0] = 3.0;
V[0][1] = 4.0;
```

In C++11:

```
vector<vector<double>> V; 
V.emplace_back({3.0, 4.0});
```

If instead, it makes more sense to use a `std::vector` of `std::pair`s, you can do it like so:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> V;
V.push_back({3.0, 4.0});
```

Accessing an element of the pair will look like either `V[0].first` or `V[1].second`.